# JavaFX Validate coordinates in Spinner

Tags: javafx, spinner

I have two Spinner to insert in database. In the controller:

```
@FXML
private Spinner<Double> latSpinner, lonSpinner;
```

`latSpinner` is the latitude coordinate and `lonSpinner` is the longitude coordinate.

In FXML:

```
<Spinner fx:id="latSpinner" editable="true" prefWidth="85.0">
                            <valueFactory>
                                <SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory min="-90" max="90" initialValue="0"
                                                                               amountToStepBy="0.0001"/>
                            </valueFactory>
                        </Spinner>

<Spinner fx:id="lonSpinner" editable="true" prefWidth="85.0">
                            <valueFactory>
                                <SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory min="-90" max="90" initialValue="0"
                                                                               amountToStepBy="0.0001"/>
                            </valueFactory>
                        </Spinner>
```

My question. How can i validate both spinner coding in order to:

1. Type **only digit** and **minus (-)** in **1st character** string,
   otherwise `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()`.
2. Type **digit** until the **max lenght**,(ex: -89.9999 max lenght is 7
   excluding the dot and 89.9999 max lenght is 6 excluding the dot), otherwise `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()`.
3. Show label spinner in **format #.####** (only show in **format #.##**).
4. Show unit **degree (º)** at the end of label spinner.

Thanks and sorry for my English. I appreciate any help

Comment: the spinner's editor is-a textField - for formatting/validation set its textFormatter to do as needed